# Displaying Many-to-Many relationships (Nested ListViews?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, many-to-many

I appreciate that this may be a fairly simple question - but I'm having quite a bit of trouble (as a fledgeling ASP.NET developer). I've gained a number of ideas from SO and Google with no luck and I think I'm beginning to over-think this, it seems such a standard scenario that I believe I'm missing something obvious.

I have for example, three standard example tables - note the Many-to-Many relationship.

```
Students
- student_id
- forename
- surname

Courses
- course_id
- course_name

StudentCourses
- studentcourse_id
- course_id
- student_id
```

I'd like to display these on my ASP.NET 3.5 Web Application in a way that looks similar to (the last column being a button to allow them to edit the Student information):

```
Students:
#  Name          Courses                 Actions
1  Joe Bloggs    Maths, English          [Manage]
2  Arthur Sleep  English                 [Manage]
3  Andy Mann     Maths, German, French   [Manage]
```

The "courses" column is a list of the courses that the student is currently enrolled upon. This could be empty (not yet enrolled) or contain a list (comma delimited or a standard unordered HTML list, I'm not precious) of their currently enrolled courses. This would not be a massive list as a student can only enrol on a handful of courses at any one time.

I've tried a number of solutions, ranging from asp:Repeater's to my current favourite, the ListView that came with 3.5. I'm using LINQ to SQL as my data layer (in case it's important due to LINQs complicated support for Many-to-Many relationships).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, you could add a couple of new properties to your "Student" class as follows (in C#):

```
public IEnumerable<Course> Courses
{
    get { return CourseRepository.GetCoursesByStudentId(this.Student_Id); }
}

//Aggregate course names into a comma-separated list
public string CoursesDescription 
{
    get 
    {
        if (!Courses.Any())
            return "Not enrolled in any courses";

        return Courses.Aggregate(string.Empty, (currentOutput, c) =>
              (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentOutput)) ?
              string.Format("{0}, {1}", currentOutput, c.Course_Name) :  c.Course_Name );
    }  
}
```

Now when you'll only need one repeater (bound to your students collection), as the need for the sub-repeater is removed by the "CoursesDescription" property on the Student class.

As an aside, I would highly recommend naming your tables in the singular (i.e. you name them after what 1 row represents).  Also, there is a strong case for removing the identity column from your StudentCourses table and replacing it with a composite key across Student_Id and Course_Id.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a great solution, I think it suits me great as I do want to use a comma-separated list in this instance (though - this solution wouldn't work as easy for a UL & LI's (or at least not as elegantly)?). Thanks for the good reply! :)

Comment: Oh, the asides. I'm not overly sure about the removal of the plural from the table names (though agree they shouldn't be on column names). Though, you are probably right about the composite key - no need for that.

Comment: Hi, glad you like my suggestion.  If you need a list (ul..li) then you could use a stringbuilder.  I tend to avoid putting HTML mark-up in my classes if I can help it though.

Comment: thats the nice thing about passing a List to the repeater its very flexible. The above solution seems a good option too though. +1

Comment: Hi, would it be possible for you to paste the code that implements: CourseRepository.GetCoursesByStudentId(this.Student_Id)

Answer (score 4):

You can use nested repeaters. The example below calls a secondary method in the code behind file which return a List. You can access all the course information from this. I could get it working with a method from a repository class so used the code below to get around this:

```
protected List<tblStudentCourses> GetStudentCoursesByStudentID(int id)
{
return studentRepository.GetStudentCoursesByStudentID(id).ToList();
}
```

Here is the full example:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="parentRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="myDataSource">
<HeaderTemplate>          
 Header HTML         
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>

    <asp:Repeater ID="availabilityRepeater" runat="server" DataSource='<%#GetStudentCoursesByStudentID(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("studentCourseID"))) %>'>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("tblStudentCourses.courseName")  %><br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

    Student Name example: <%#Eval("studentName")%>

</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    Footer HTML 
</FooterTemplate>
```

This may not be the best solution but it is a working solution so i hope it helps you

Comment: This seems to be ok, gives me the option to be able to customise the HTML in the sub-repeater which is good. Thanks!